# Where does Localstack run EMR steps?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, localstack

I have a job Im trying to run in Localstack. It has a number of steps that execute various scripts, append env to bashrc, and ultimately runs a jar. Steps that set up the env look something to the effect of:

```
[
  {
    "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
    ...
    "Properties": "",
    "Args": [
      "bash",
      "-c",
      "source /home/hadoop/.bashrc && echo -e \"\\export .....;\" >> /home/hadoop/.bashrc;"
    ],
    "Type": "CUSTOM_JAR"
  },
  {
    "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
    ...
    "Properties": "",
    "Args": [
      "bash",
      "-c",
      "source /home/hadoop/.bashrc && aws s3 sync s3://.....;"
    ],
    "Type": "CUSTOM_JAR"
  },
  {
    "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
    ...
    "Properties": "",
    "Args": [
      "bash",
      "-c",
      "source /home/hadoop/.bashrc && (cat /home/hadoop/.bashrc && source /home/hadoop/.bashrc && env && .....; export.... \" >> /home/hadoop/.bashrc)"
    ],
    "Type": "CUSTOM_JAR"
  },
  ....
]
```

That works fine in AWS, but in Localstack when a script uses a variable from an export that was appended to bashrc, it is empty. If I check the localstack container - there is nothing appended to bashrc and no scripts have been synced from S3. So my questions are:

1. Where do my steps get executed? I do not see containers being spun up to act as my cluster.
2. How can I get this job to run locally without worksarounds like running scripts on the localstack container manually, because that would defeat the purpose of replicating prod-like behavior locally.